# Automatically select shipping method in Admin Order

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods, adminform

I have created a custom version of Order which exists only in Admin. These Orders will never use any shipping option other than Free Shipping, so the client doesn't want to click "Get shipping methods and rates" then select "Free Shipping", which is the only available option.

I have:

- Enabled free shipping for Admin only.
- Filtered shipping methods so only freeshipping is shown for this type of Order.

To make the selection, I tried:

- replacing `create/shipping/method/form.phtml` with a static form.phtml that is only the container and select for free shipping, already checked.
- Adding calls to `order.loadShippingRates()` and `order.setShippingMethod('freeshipping')` to fire after the ajax response from `order.productGridAddSelected().`

The first method **throws a "Select a shipping method" error**, and while the second works, it adds a second or two to each call to `order.productGridAddSelected()`, which isn't optimal.

Since this is a completely separate version of Order, I don't mind having it load a modified version of sales.js, but even when I have added calls to `order.loadShippingRates()` and `order.setShippingMethod('freeshipping')` in sales.js I get the "Select a shipping method" error.

I am thinking the fix needs to happen in sales.js, but I'm not sure where.

per request, the code I am using to return only freeshipping :

```
public function getShippingRates()
{
    if (empty($this->freeShipHolder)) {
        $groups = $this->getAddress()->getGroupedAllShippingRates();

        foreach ($groups as $carrier) {
            foreach ($carrier as $rate) {
                if ($rate['carrier'] == 'freeshipping') {
                    $this->freeShipHolder['freeshipping'][] = $rate;
                }
            }
        }
        return $this->freeShipHolder;
    }
    return $this->freeShipHolder;
}
```

...`/Create/Shipping/Method/Form.php`

That part works with no issues, but if it's informative....

Comment: I don't know how you've structured your module but maybe you can set a default value in the ``config.xml``? Or, can you show the code you have for filtering shipping methods so only free shipping is shown?

Comment: Code posted above. I'm not sure on the xml fix though....

Comment: If freeshipping is the only available option, why is it not selected automatically? Does the dropdown contain a blank option?

Comment: There's no dropdown, just a radio button. I am guessing because I am only filtering out the other options on this specific variant of order. There are other options available for the store frontend and other types of admin orders.

Comment: Well I'm not sure how your order form looks like or is generated so I'm having trouble imagining it but I think you're better off loading the form with the option already selected instead of relaying on javascript. Maybe you can set it in the form class, in the _prepareObject method or something. Did you build custom admin blocks for it? Check those blocks. Or else maybe you can set it in the controller but I'm not so sure if that one's possible

Comment: Wherever you added the control like ``$fieldset->addField(..., 'type' => 'select', 'options' => $options..  `` adf something like ``'value' => 'freeshipping'``

Comment: Can you tell me how you solved your problem

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/149529)